# A python 3.5 script not printing results in windows command shell or powershell, only in the interpreter

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying out some data science tutorials with python and can't get print to, well, print! when I run a .py in windows command shell or powershell.  Print does work when I use the interpreter, but I have to type it in line by line (I'm not seeing how to run a .py as a file in the interpreter).  I'm attaching snips of the file, and a snip of me running in the interpreter.  I tried to attach snips of what happens when I run in command shell and powershell, but apparently I need at least 10 reputation points before I can post more than 2 links.  Admittedly, those snips weren't interesting; there is no error and nothing printed.  It just runs and returns to the prompt.

Also, as a test, I saved a .py file that simply does print ("Hello") and it does print correctly in windows command prompt and powershell.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Casie
[PY script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NTEH.jpg)
[Snip From Python Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cJXC.jpg)

Comment: Shouldn't the code after the comment be un-indented?

Comment: Next time, please copy and paste *text* into your question, not images. Format it as code (also the error output) to show it precisely as it came out.

Answer (score 0):

Is that image from the IDLE console? To run the script you are editing, use menu `Run > Run Module`, or <kbd>F5</kbd>. Every python GUIs has an equivalent feature.

To run an arbitrary script from inside the commandline interpreter, say `mywork.py`: As long as it's in the working directory that you were in when you started the interpreter, you run it (once) by typing `import mywork`. (As you can see, its name must be a python identifier.)

**Edit:** You'd get to the bottom of this a lot quicker if you'd put `print("Hello, world")` in a script by itself and run it. From over here it looks like it would print just fine, proving there's nothing wrong with your python interpreter.

Your script has a bug, though: As soon as you enter the function `random_kid()`, you leave it again since you `return` a value on the first line. All those `print` statements are never executed. Why you think it works differently with `%run` I can't say, but for sure this function *cannot* print any output.

Comment: But you should really figure out what's going wrong with your current approach.Are you typing `python mywork.py` in CMD and not seeing the output of `print`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Yes, that's what's happening.  The script I'm running is in the PYScript image I posted yesterday.  If I run it directly in python (using %run), it runs and goes back to the prompt.  If I run it via CMD (c:\Anaconda3\python conditionalprobability.py), it runs and goes back to the prompt.  Does not return the print.  If I run it from within the IDLE console using run > run module, as you suggested, it launches Python 3.5.0 shell with this: 
>>> 
============== RESTART: C:\Anaconda3\conditionalprobability.py ==============
>>>

Comment: Thanks alexis.  I had already tried a simple print, and had indicated that in my original question ("Also, as a test, I saved a .py file that simply does print ("Hello") and it does print correctly in windows command prompt and powershell.").

Thanks for your comments on the script.  This script is directly out of a book, Data Science From Scratch, pg. 71.  I will try to fix the script.  I'm new to python!

Comment: Oops, you did write that! Sorry. (But you left it out of your diagnosis of the problem, which still sounds like it always happens.) The script is out of a book, but as @JavaNut13 wrote under your question, it looks like you messed up the indentation when you copy-pasted it. And evidently you ended up with different indentation in your different interfaces...

Comment: After the `return` statement, everything should be indented 4 spaces less (so, no indentation except inside the for-loop).

Comment: Yep, a friend just pointed out the indention issue.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Ah, I just now saw @JavaNut13's comment and the comment to paste code directly in.  Will do that next time.  Thanks all for helping a phython newbie.

Comment: Good luck and enjoy python!